# Deny access to a file for all other processes?

Tags: java, file, java-io

I'm writing an application (for educational purposes), which needs to use database management system (I wrote my own extremely primitive DBMS, it is part of the task). And I want to ensure that at any time my application is running contents of all tables are correct. For that purposes I wrote method, which looks through each file and make necessary checks. The problem is that I want to call this method only once, when application starts and deny access to files to ensure that nobody changed their contents while my program is working.

I use the following approach. When application starts, I initialize **InputStreamReader** and **OutputStreamWriter**, store them and close them only when my application is terminated.

**Part of initialization method:**

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true); 
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");

this.tables.get(table).put("fis", fis);
this.tables.get(table).put("fos", fos);
this.tables.get(table).put("isr", isr);
this.tables.get(table).put("osw", osw);
```

**Close method:**

```
try {
    for(Map<String, Object> table_map: tables.values()) {
        OutputStreamWriter osw = (OutputStreamWriter)table_map.get("osw"); 
        InputStreamReader isr = (InputStreamReader)table_map.get("isr"); 

        if (osw != null)
            osw.close();
        if (isr != null)
            isr.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new DBException("Closing error");
}
```

Partly, this approach works, because when I try to modify any of these files using MS Notepad, I get the following error

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process"

That's what I want to see. But if I use Notepad++,  I can make any modifications when my application is running, that's not what I expect to see. So what can I do to ensure that no other process can modify my files?

I tried to use **FileLock**, but it denies access only for my process, if I'm not mistaken.

Sorry for my poor English, hope you will understand my question anyway.

Comment: Instead of using a Map, I would use an object which holds the `osw` and `isr`. I would buffer them to improve performance and I wouldn't store the original streams as you don't need those.  I would use a proper IDE which will help you write, run and debug the code.

Comment: The simplest way to deny access to a file is to rename it.  This way you won;t be able to access it unless you know what the file is called, you can event change its extension.

Comment: Yup, renaming the file usual works a treat... just be sure to rename it something "highly unique", like a filename.UUID.ext. See the doco: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: *Sorry for my poor English* > For what it's worth, your question reads very nicely. Probably better than many efforts written by so-called native speakers :-)

Comment: Also, I suggest making your Table class IDisposable to close the underlying streams, and if you don't yet have a class that "wraps" the input/output for a table then it's time to create one.

Comment: @corlettk This is Java not C#.

Comment: @Duncan: Doh!!! But I can't delete or edit that comment now. Sigh.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Presumably one would need to be extremely careful to handle all error conditions correctly to ensure the file is renamed to its original name on program exit.

Comment: @DuncanJones That depends on the behaviour you want but you can have tool which renames them back or renames them on restart of the application.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, in this Map I store some other variables like maximum primary key for current table and table's fields. In that case do you think I should use object for stream variables or keep using HashMap? Anyway, I will not store original streams, they are really useless, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a problem worth solving. Whatever approach you take, someone with the correct privileges can probably undo your file protection and could make changes anyway.

It is best to focus on gracefully handling invalid data and otherwise trusting what is in the file. Adding some kind of integrity check (per row or table) will make it harder for someone to accidentally or maliciously change your data in a way that leaves it looking "valid".

Comment: Well, at first I want to answer you that this integrity check is rather resource intensive. For example, I check whether rows with higher primary key values go after rows with lower ones. To perform this check, method needs to read the whole file and to parse each string to get primary key value. But then I thought a little bit and decided that this check is useless enough. If users try to intentionally screw up program's correct work, they should be ready for unexpected results. I need just to prevent program's crash, so, I suppose, row checks in main methods (such as insert) will be enough.

Comment: Small remark - I didn't decided that this resource intensive check is useless at all. It is helpful when application starts, but there is no point in calling it each time I want to select, update, insert or delete data. Hence there is no need in locking files actually.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the section "Platform dependencies" in the `java.nio.channels.FileLock` docsyou see that:

- `FileLocks` are not (only) for locking inside *one* JVM but for all processes on the computer.
- File locks (note the different spelling) are greatly platform and configuration specific.

So you basicyll have to ask yourself: What protection do I *really* need?

If you only want to guard against running *your* programm multiple times on the same data you can assume that your programm "behaves well" and

- use `FileLocks` or
- use a marker lock file or
- use a "dirty/locked" marker inside the file

If you want to protect against *every other* program then you are lost as you have seen in the Notepad++ scenario: Considering all platforms and all possible ways to circumvent locks and using Java- you have no chance.

Comment: FileLocks aren't for 'locking inside one JVM' at all. They only work between processes. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP: I'm confused: The JavaDoc says: "_The locks held on a particular file by a single Java virtual machine do
not overlap._" which means you __can__ use `FileLock` within your program. A quick test program verified this on Linux. On the other hand the same doc says: "_File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine._" So you can choose whatever you want :-)